# Data structure for Google Places API JSON in Yesod

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, yesod, aeson

I am new to Haskell and Yesod development.
I try to parse JSON from Google Web Api using Aeson.
My JSON is like

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
       {
         "geometry" : {
             "location" : {
             "lat" : 47.2487941,
             "lng" : 39.7119239
          },
         "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 47.2488398,
              "lng" : 39.71313905
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 47.24865699999999,
              "lng" : 39.71151884999999
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
     "id" : "5aae9c47cad3016c64d3cc2c8d438ae656c8c0af",
     "name" : "AMAKS Congress hotel",
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 2304,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116238492021115373516/photos\"\u003eDmitry Semenov\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAP5F6Xu0nGvQ8wjAyY4ENNKEWzw8CohQU_2Z15oXWIQOvzwAOBQduK4OQfh-nRyw0iKCwLMS2o9fKanMcxpC4xop22SrxZI45OZWmvC-bTf80kJlgdnlU0q-AsncUxcP6sbfWMaTmAPCsqiAFLJhHwHD93VXCvyV2V4pC2CUpWKAEhBAr9aS0xoapQvNmvcUYfU7GhT3IKDXEdZ49LtEeMXMaBQKlNZ6DQ",
           "width" : 4096
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJNT2qOT7r40ARrxvwbj2Huxg",
     "rating" : 4.1,
     "reference" : "CmRRAAAAUR4QujRBtpkltqU51qCjuihX1JDEgX9ijFzkTeWGWkeQkw4spvaKqCPUrYit4jNs5AyT1hV-y0M72U2CtOTYgT_6chw5KAq0sB3l1k18BOoioDJqTL6HQ_kvqNn62ISIEhA-lNI9YXDt-cjErgJqHjGFGhQpYucBzRg9yilMU0MEn6b293lVUQ",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "types" : [
        "bowling_alley",
        "bakery",
        "lodging",
        "restaurant",
        "food",
        "store",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
     ],
     "vicinity" : "проспект Михаила Нагибина, 19, Ростов-на-Дону"
  }, 
  / more items here
  "status" : "ok"
}
```

I created data for representing JSON:

```
data Restaurant = Restaurant {status :: Text} deriving  (Show, Generic)
```

And it works, I can extract status. But when it comes to more complicated enclosed fields such as "results", I don't know how to describe and use it.
So what should I write instead of ??? in

```
data Restaurant = Restaurant {results :: ???, status :: Text} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

And then how can I get access to items inside (name, rating, etc.)?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need your own representation as `Restaurant`? You can use `Data.Aeson.Value` as it is. If need then I think you should to design it without the json example then you can design parser.

Comment: And, the json example isn't valid.